# Data inserted into jointable entity always coming up as null - playframework

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

Been struggling with this one for a couple of days.  I've got 2 models course and student. Each model is used as a form to register courses and students. I've created a separate entity called timetable which has a course object and a student object, instead of having a manytomany relationship. Here are the releavant sections of the code

Objects/lists from the class model

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Timtable> timetable;
```

Objects/lists from the student model

```
@Required
@Email
@Id
public String email;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Timetable> timetable;
```

Objects from the timetable model

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="email")
public Student student;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
public Course course;
```

Now, I "add" a course to the timetable through a form. The form has 2 hidden inputs with the email and the id. The mySQL table updates, but with NULL values instead of the values that are populated in the form. If I change the timetable variables from objects to primitive types it updates correctly, but when I change back the objects, and the manytoone/onetomany relationship, it just has NULL again. Any ideas on why this is happening?

I'm new to RDMS and ORMs. I've trawled a fair few resources to get the above code together. This is a good one: http://uaihebert.com/jpa-mini-book-first-steps-and-detailed-concepts/22/ (where I got the new class called timetable idea from) and this: http://lazylightening-tech.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/manytomany-ebean-example.html the Beisar dude has also posted some really good stuff on it. I've been over too many of his posts on here and the google group to get to link, but most people have error messages. I'm not getting an error, it just isn't registering what I'm submitting. Can anyone help?

Comment: I found this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561257/playframework-relational-database-issue-foreign-key-is-always-set-to-null The timetable entity has a setter, so I'm going to try calling that from my controller. This will be tomorrow though, I've got to go to bed!

Answer (score 0):

try writting up manual getters and setters..even i encountered this problem..if you are using eclipse then you can do..

```
right click + source + generate getters and setters
```

moreover go through this-
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaEbean

PS - Because Ebean class enhancement occurs after compilation, do not expect Ebean-generated getter/setters to be available at compilation time. If you’d prefer to code with them directly, either add the getter/setters explicitly yourself, or ensure that your model classes are compiled before the remainder of your project, eg. by putting them in a separate subproject.